# Python: Finding a string within a string

Tags: string, python-3.x

I have two parameters, both strings, and I need to find the index of where the second string is found within the first string. I can do this when it's just one character but not when its more. Here is an example of the one I can do:

```
  for i, j in enumerate(primary):
        if final == j:
            index = i
            break
```

This is what I tried for the problem:

```
    for i in range (0,len(initial),1):
        for j in range (len(initial), i, -1):
            if initial[i:j] == last:
                index_str = i
                break
```

However, it always returns "None" so can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Assuming that this is homework and you can't just use the built-in [`index`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) or `find` methods of string objects, you probably just need to add a `return` statement to your function. Of course it's a little difficult to say, since you aren't showing your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need the index() method. Example usage (taken from [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_index.htm))

```
str1 = "this is string example....wow!!!";
str2 = "exam";

print str1.index(str2);
```

Comment: Can't use index method otherwise I would. But what I have actually works, I just forgot a return statement -_-

Comment: Glad you've sorted it but that would have been great information to put in the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

The string.find method can do that.

```
"somestring".find("str")
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find